# Do Hogwarts and Ilvermorny outlets exist in Falkland Islands and Hawaii?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Ok, so let me explain.

1. Hogwarts is in Britain.
2. Falkland Islands is part of Britain.
3. Falkland Islands is next to Argentina.

Also, we know that Narcissa Malfoy didn’t want Draco to go to Durmstrang because it’s far away. Many parents might feel that way: Falkland Islands is far away from Britain, so does it have their own Hogwarts? Same with Hawaii: It’s part of USA, yet does it have its own Ilvermorny?

Comment: Given how generally sparse wizarding schools seem to be in the world (as a consequence of minuscule wizarding population), I think it's more probable that folks from Falkland and Hawaii would simply travel to their respective schools. Now a separate _research centre_ or an observatory would be cool

Comment: The population of the Falklands is less than 4000 people.  The odds are pretty good there are no wizards living there.  There are probably some in Hawaii though.

Comment: The Falkland Islands are not part of Britain. They are a British Overseas Territory and are self-governing.

Comment: @DJClayworth - But they are British citizens.

Comment: Mostly yes, though not necessarily.

Comment: What do you mean by "outlets"?

Comment: Most of wizard travel is actually instantenous. Port keys, floo network, apparatio.

Comment: You forgot that Alaska is just as far away as Hawaii.

Comment: To add to the above, muggle Falkland Islanders who wish to continue education past the age of 16 do so in Winchester, England. So it wouldn't be extraordinary for Wizarding families there to send their children all the way to Hogwarts.

Answer (score 11):

There's no good indication that separate parts of the world have separate  *outreach centres* to service children who live far away. Each of the main schools that we know of (Hogwarts, Dumrstrang, etc.) seem to be [boarding schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarding_school), enabling children within their respective catchments to travel to school at their convenience, remain during term time and then return home or stay on site over the holidays if no family are available to look after them.

**In the event of a wizard child born to a family from the Falklands, they'd presumably just travel to the nearest port of entry to the mainland UK then travel to Hogwarts via the Hogwarts Express like every other child in their year.**

For the record, since the population of the Falklands recently voted overwhelmingly (by a margin of 99.8%) to remain a sovereign British Overseas Territory, it's quite unlikely that any of the families would send their children to the South American school [Castelobruxo](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/castelobruxo) as their 'home school' despite its proximity to the islands.

Comment: Is there reason to assume that wizarding families care about muggle national politics, or that they even vote for them? I’m not sure why that’s relevant to the answer.

Comment: @Thunderforge - This was an election where more than 90% of the population voted with nil spoiled ballots and only three dissenters out of more than 1500 voters. There's a better than nine out of ten chance that any wizards families on the island voted and a better than 99% chance that they voted to remain British Citizens. Obviously they might have been part of the small proportion who didn't vote "yay", but that seems unlikely, especially since (on an island that small) they'd be trying to lay low rather than drawing attention to themselves.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in Valorum's answer, there probably are no "branches" of Hogwarts other than the main school that's mentioned.
To me, the biggest pointer to this is the passage I found on Pottermore's page for [The Hogwarts Express](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express) (emphasis mine):

> [After the imposition of the International Statute of Secrecy in 1692],  it became a matter of urgency to find some more discreet method of transporting hundreds of wizarding children from all over Britain to their secret school in the Highlands of Scotland.
>
> Portkeys were therefore arranged **at collecting points all over Britain**.

Since portkeys were setup all over Britain, it stands to reason that no matter where in Britain you are, you need to go to the "main" Hogwarts.

As to Ilvermony, we can take an educated guess that it's the only one as well since [it was modelled after Hogwarts](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny).

Comment: I am so offended that you think America is not capable of doing things are own way! Yes, an Irish witch started Ilvermorny, and yes, the idea was to make an American Hogwarts, but they are extremely different. Do you think 300 years after we became our own country that we are still modeling after hogwarts? No! I don't think we have Hawaii and Alaska outlets, but not because we copy hogwarts.

Answer (score 2):

They do not have their own outlets. In a [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools) article it stated:

> Occasionally, too, the magical community in a given country is tiny or far-flung and correspondence courses have been found a more cost-effective means of educating the young.

So it would make sense that Hawaii, Alaska, and Falkland islands would use correspondence courses or go to the nearest wizarding school that spoke their own language. So, as the Falkland Islands speak English, it would not make logical sense for them to go to Castelobruxo, where it is mostly made of Spanish and Portuguese speakers. So they would take a Portkey, Side-Along Apparation, or Floo Powder to London. Then they would ride the Hogwarts Express like an ordinary kid. The same would go for Alaska or Hawaii if they did not use correspondence courses.

Comment: would you mind posting the link to the Pottermore article - some are written by JKR and are thus essentially canon / true, while others are more akin to Buzzfeed

Comment: @NKCampbell I've edited in the link for the user